# Pararell instance of tkinter application window python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to create some simple tkinter python app (like StickyNotes on Windows), i have create the class **mainApplication** and i do not know how to by just simply triggering the button create another instance of this class which will be displayed pararell to other window (or even multiple windows). I know how to assigned function to pushButton, and other simple stuff but the problem is with this pararell window displaying. Thanks in advance for help.

```
class mainApplication(Frame):
    _ids = count(0)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """ """
        self.id = next(self._ids)
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.minsize(width=200,height=100)
        self.parent.geometry(('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (200, 100, 1700, 0+self.id*100)))
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        """ """
        self.parent.title("a2l")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        style = Style()
        style.configure("TFrame", background="#333")

        frame1 = Frame(self, style="TFrame")
        frame1.pack(fill=X)

        self.lbl0 = Label(frame1, text="api", width=7, background="#333", foreground = "red")
        self.lbl0.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.closeButton = Button(self, text="new", command = self.createNewInstance)
        self.closeButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        #=======================================================================
        # self.generateButton = Button(self, text="GENERATE", command = self.)
        # self.generateButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        #=======================================================================

    def createNewInstance(self):
        y = mainApplication()
        return  y
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    x = mainApplication(root).pack(side="top", expand=False)
    Tk().mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you have example code you can share?

Comment: I just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create more than one `Tk()` window in one application with tkinter. Instead tkinter provides a widget called `Toplevel` which can be useful for this kind of thing.

It creates another window which can exist along side the `Tk()` window and alongside other `Toplevel` widgets.

You could use this to create a series of persistent windows with whatever text or widgets you wanted on them at any kind of trigger including a `Button`.

See my example below for a demonstration:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.top = [] #list to contain the Toplevel widgets
        self.entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Create window", command=self.command)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def command(self): #called when button is pressed
        self.top.append(Toplevel(self.root)) #adds new Toplevel to the list
        Label(self.top[len(self.top)-1], text=self.entry.get()).pack() #Adds label equal to the entry widget to the new toplevel

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```